# How Can I Write hex value in file to until my write byte?

Tags: vb.net

How Can I fill a file with "FF" hex values?

I want my program to take the value I enter into a textbox and use it to create a file that is that many megabytes in size filled with FF hex values.

[image]

I've used this code but, to write 10 mb files, but only the last hex value is FF.

[image]

```vb
Dim hex As String = "FF"
    Using fs As New FileStream("huge_dummy_file", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        For Each byteHex As String In hex.Split()
            fs.Seek(TextBox1.Text * 1024 * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            fs.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(byteHex, 16))
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question and add a tag clarifying which language you are using, and perhaps also add that information to the question.

Comment: Go into your project's setting and turn on Option Strict.  You are only writing the value after seeking to the end of the file so it only writes it at the end.